# FORM by NIKHEF: unexpected behavior wrt summation

Tags: linear-programming

I have two almost identical FORM  (by NIKHEF) scripts here:

[script_1](http://147.213.122.82/~andrej/Hzz2587Qj/t_567.frm)

[script_2](http://147.213.122.82/~andrej/Hzz2587Qj/test_Zmol.frm)

which differ only in summation at the end. In first case the summation in done in one step, in the second case summation it is done in two steps.

When I subtract the results of the two previous scripts I get a non-zero result

http://147.213.122.82/~andrej/Hzz2587Qj/resDiff.txt

which is a mystery to me. Can somebody explain me, why the two outputs are different?

Comment: You are asking us to debug your code for you, and you are not even making an effort to explain your problem. I am afraid that not many people will feel inclined to answer questions like this.

Comment: Should I explain the problem of computing traces in one-loop diagrams in covariant quark model with FORM where the script which I post is a very reduced and purpose non-working torso of the original code? Well, I think my question is OK: it is fully explicit with code included and FORM version also (in the links).

Comment: If you think is OK. You should leave it like it is. But I think it does not comply with what is expected in this site.

Answer (score 0):

The result I get is actually zero, only FORM is unable to see it is zero. It is linked to labeling of dummy indices and command "renumber" solves the issue. Here is linked to the help I was given at a different forum:

https://github.com/vermaseren/form/issues/343